# Sort command inconsistent behavior

Tags: centos, sort, locale

I want to sort two files but I cannot get consistent results. It seems there are problems with collation but I cannot understand the reason. In sample files separator is a single space:

**file1:**

```
a
b
B
A
```

**file2:**

```
a 1
b 0
B 1
A 0
```

I use `sort -k1,1` to sort these files and the output is:

**sorted1:**

```
a
A
b
B
```

**sorted2:**

```
A 0
a 1
b 0
B 1
```

I need those sorted files in a `join` and its currently complaining that the one of files is not sorted.

In my environment `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_ALL` are not set, `LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`

With `LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1` the output is:

**sorted11:**

```
A
B
a
b
```

**sorted22:**

```
A 0
B 1
a 1
b 0
```

I don't need a specific ordering, I just want it to be able to join the results. This way `join` works. To be safe I can also prepend `join` with `LC_ALL=C`.

**My question**

Why in `sorted1` `a` is *before* `A` and in `sorted2` `a` is *after* `A`? Whatever the collation is, it is for both `sort` commands and I am sorting based on column 1 that is identical in both input files.

**Added output of `ltrace -e strcoll`**

**file1**

```
sort->strcoll("B","A") =1
sort->strcoll("a","b") =-1 
sort->strcoll("a","A") =-7
a
sort->strcoll("b","A") =1
A
sort->strcoll("b","B") =-7
b
B
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

**file2**

```
sort->strcoll("B 1","A 0") =1
sort->strcoll("a 1","b 0") =-1 
sort->strcoll("a 1","A 0") =1
A 0
sort->strcoll("a 1","B 1) =-1
a 1
sort->strcoll("b 0","B 1") =-1
b 0
B 1
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this, what version of sort are you using ?

Comment: @User112638726, I am using sort 8.22 on centos 7

Comment: Check that you don't have some unprintable characters in the file, like `\0`. For example with `recode us..dump file`.

Comment: @jimmij, I checked the files with `od -c` there are only the alphanumeric characters, spaces and newlines. To be sure I just tried `echo -e "a\nA" | sort -k1,1` and `echo -e "a 1\nA 0" | sort -k1,1`, same behavior.

Comment: @Ashkan And what if you put `LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF8` at the beginning of the line?

Comment: @jimmij, makes no difference. And sorry I had a typo in my question it is `en_US.UTF-8`. I also tested with `en_US.UTF8` anyway, same results.

Comment: Can't reproduce either with 8.21 or 8.23. What's the output when run under `ltrace -e strcoll`?

Comment: You probably want to use `LC_ALL=C` anyway for `join`, especially if the file contains non-ASCII characters as all UTF-8 glibc locales are buggy in that many different characters and collating elements sort the same there.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, I have edited the question to add the output of `ltrace -e strcoll`.

Comment: Thanks. That strcoll output shows it's sorting on the whole line, not on the first field. Are you sure that was on `sort -k1,1` and not `sort -k1`? Have you got an alias or function definition on `sort`? What does `type sort` tell you? Have you got a specific setting on LC_CTYPE, one that would say for instance that the space character is not a blank?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, output of type is: `sort is /usr/bin/sort`. Environment variable `LC_CTYPE`  is not set. I am sure I am using `sort -k1,1`

Comment: Also tried `alias`, and it showed no alias for sort.

Comment: Do you see the same strcoll()s with LC_ALL=C? Do you get anything different for `printf 'a 1\nA 0\n' | ltrace -e strcoll sort -t ' ' -k1,1`?

Comment: Is the absence of space after the `=` in the ltrace output because you removing them before posting here, or could it be some indication of something else going wrong, possibly related?

Comment: Yes I forgot to type spaces. I had no internet access on that machine.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, if I set `LC_ALL` to `C` the output of `ltrace` is like the `sorted1` and `sorted2`. No `strcoll` is there. `printf` make no difference, same inconsistent result.

Comment: I can reproduce with the sort in http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/26640824/dir/centos_7/com/coreutils-8.22-11.el7.x86_64.rpm.html, which seems completely broken in that regard, not with the base 8.22 from gnu.org. I can see the CentOS one has a large internationalisation patch which is probably the culprit. You may want to report it as a bug to CentOS if not already known.

Answer (score 4):

As Stéphane Chazelas said in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224164/sort-command-inconsistent-behavior?noredirect=1#comment381035_224164), it is a bug in the specific implementation of `coreutils` (in `coreutils-8.22-11.el7`) by CentOS/Red Hat, more specifically  in the buggy internationalisation patch (`coreutils-i18n.patch`) they wrote and applied on top of GNU's `coreutils-8.22`.

I reported it [here](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=9289) to CentOS and also [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1255107) to Red Hat. It was already [known](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1148347) at Red Hat and fixed there in `coreutils-8.22-13.el7`.

That one is not available yet for [CentOS](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/) at this time (2015-08-20).

For completeness, note that the bug was also (incorrectly as the bug was not there) [reported upstreams](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18540) (at GNU's) where you'll find some more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your default collation(en_US.UTF-8) cause to this. You should set **LC_COLLATE** value to order the text as directed.

```
 LC_COLLATE='C' sort -k1 file1
```

Comment: My question is why my default collation works this way? One of these can be true `a is before A` or `a is after A` not both. How can a collation result in both?

Comment: Not `sort -k1`, `sort -k1` is the same as `sort`. It sorts on the section of the line that starts at the first field, so basically the whole line. `sort -k1,1` to sort on the first field.

Comment: @Ashkan I think a collation could declare that `A` and `a` are equal. The sort command would then sort by later characters on the line, or failing that, leave them in the order they originally appeared in the file. E.g. `ac`, `aa`, `Ab`,  should be sorted as `aa`, `Ab`, `ac` , not `Ab`, `aa`, `ac` or `aa`, `ac`, `Ab`.

Comment: FYI neither `LC_ALL=C` nor `LC_COLLATE=C` helped solve the problem on my side:
(1) `# export LC_ALL=C`
`# printf "%s\n" "1000|a" "103|a" "1034|a" | sort --field-separator='|' --key=1` outputs:
`1000|a
1034|a
103|a`
(2) `# export LC_COLLATE=C`
`# printf "%s\n" "1000|a" "103|a" "1034|a" | sort --field-separator='|' --key=1`
outputs: `1000|a
1034|a
103|a
`
where the expected order is `1000|a 103|a 1034|a`